# How to configure https for a UWP Desktop Bridge app hosting a PWA via a Kestrel Server

Tags: ssl, https, tls1.2, kestrel-http-server, desktop-bridge

I have a desktop bridge app which uses a worker service to host a PWA and WebAPI with Kestrel over https

User runs the worker, and browses to the service from ff/chrome/edge

This works fine in development as the development machine has a trusted certificate installed

However, when I package it up and deploy to test machine, there is no cert and the app crashes

So, how what is the best way to do this?

Options

- Bundle a cert with the app, install it in the containers local
  store? How would this work with the browser, which wouldn't trust the
  cert as its not installed in the browser users context
- Buy a cert from a CA. How would I distribute it?
- Magic UWP trusted certs I can add to kestrel?

Comment: I found this https://dev.to/danielkun/where-is-https-for-iot-49ao helpful

Comment: And this https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/121163/how-do-i-run-proper-https-on-an-internal-network

Comment: And this https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it seems you can't

In 2015 certs can not be issued to IPv4 or IPv6 address and must be a FQDN with a public top level domain

TLS is not just about encryption, but also identification, private ips can't be publicly identified

And PWA's need https to work, so options..

1. Self-signed certificate, which won't be trusted and show the user a
   nasty message
2. Publicly host the PWA and certify that domain, then
   call back to the loopback address 127.0.0.1 over http to communicate
   with the running worker, this is considered secure. I have done this
   and it does work, but means my app can only communicate with the user
   on the same machine

There are other options that need you to have control of the network dns - which I won't have